# add a json to a tabledit select parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tabledit

I am using jquery tabledit plugin and I need to use a JSON from a URL to feed the select of a tabledit.
I have my JSON from a remote URL (getpsp.php) looking like:

```
[{"id":"2698","psp":"Paypal"},{"id":"2699","psp":"Unknown"},{"id":"2677","psp":"Stripe"},{"id":"2678","psp":"AmazonPay"}]
```

and i have my JS code like:

```
$('#pspmap').on('draw.dt', function() {
     $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax/getpsp.php',
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(data, status, xhr)
       {
          var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(data);
         
       },
       error: function(xhr, status, error)
       {
           
           alert("error");
       }
   });
    
      $('#pspmap').Tabledit({
          url: 'ajax/action.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          columns: {
              identifier: [0, 'id'],
              editable: [
                 [2, 'color', jsonstring]
                ]},
          deleteButton: false,
          hideIdentifier: true,
          restoreButton: false,
          onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              if (data.action == 'delete') {
                  $('#' + data.id).remove();
                  $('#pspmap').DataTable().ajax.reload();
              }
          }
      });
  });
```

I suspect the JSON to be stringified incorrecly, it should look like:
(as per example on tabledit website)

```
editable: [ [3, 'avatar', '{"1": "Black Widow", "2": "Captain America", "3": "Iron Man"}']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your response data to editable column dropdown options string like this

```js
const options = [{"id":"2698","psp":"Paypal"},{"id":"2699","psp":"Unknown"},{"id":"2677","psp":"Stripe"},{"id":"2678","psp":"AmazonPay"}];

const result = options.reduce((acc, opt, index) => {
  acc[opt.id] = opt.psp;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Then you can integrate the same as reusable function in your code.

```js
function getOptionsConfig(col, key, options) {
  const result = options.reduce((acc, opt, index) => {
      acc[opt.id] = opt.psp;
      return acc;
    }, {});
  return [col, key, JSON.stringify(result)];
}

$('#pspmap').on('draw.dt', function() {
     $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax/getpsp.php',
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(data, status, xhr) {
          $('#pspmap').Tabledit({
              url: 'ajax/action.php',
              dataType: 'json',
              columns: {
                  identifier: [0, 'id'],
                  editable: [ [2, 'color', jsonstring], getOptionsConfig(3, 'psp', data) ]},
              deleteButton: false,
              hideIdentifier: true,
              restoreButton: false,
              onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  if (data.action == 'delete') {
                      $('#' + data.id).remove();
                      $('#pspmap').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                  }
              }
          });
       },
       error: function(xhr, status, error) {
           alert("error");
       }
   });
  });
```

Comment: the line   editable: [ [2, 'color', jsonstring], getOptionsConfig(3, 'psp', data) ]}, should be like editable: [ [2, 'PSP', '{"2677":"Stripe","2678":"AmazonPay","2698":"Paypal","2699":"Unknown"}']]... I believe this is not the output given by your code (it gives me an error)

Comment: That is an example usage. If you want exactly use like this `editable: [getOptionsConfig(2, 'PSP', data) ]`.